# PHP JSON Decode Curl Object Wrong Value

Tags: php, json, api, curl, stdclass

Below is my entire code for parsing a REST API URL and my attempt at doing what I need it to do. What I need it to do is tell me the Subscription ID (which in the example below is a "7"). But every time I call it, it simply returns the expiration date. The problem is that the "7" is always going to be different depending on the client and package they have choosen. So I need to be able to tell if it's a "7", an "8", or a "232" and echo it out or assign it to a variable. How would I go about that? I can't seem to get it.

**CURL and JSON Decode**

```
$url = "HIDDEN";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($json));
echo "</pre>";

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->{'name_l'};
echo "<br />";
echo $obj->{'subscriptions'}->{7};
```

**Output of Code**

```
    stdClass Object
    (
    [ok] => 1
    [user_id] => 3
    [name] => Nathan Brown
    [name_f] => Nathan
    [name_l] => Brown
    [email] => test@email.com
    [login] => username
    [subscriptions] => stdClass Object
        (
            [7] => 2014-10-03
        )
```

`)
Brown
2014-10-03`

Comment: p.s. json_decode($json, TRUE) will return array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get confused by all the fuzz. You simply want to fetch the first [key](https://www.php.net/key) of an array (similarly, you could get the [current value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)):

```
reset($obj->subscriptions); // Just to be safe
$foo = key($obj->subscriptions); // 7
$bar = current($obj->subscriptions); // 2014-10-03
```

Comment: Okay, I have another question on this exact same topic... If I need to make another post, I don't mind, but how would I get the date to echo out now? I got the subscription number, which is "7", but how do I get the date? (ie:  2014-10-03)

Comment: If you follow the link I've provided you'll find the answer in the "See Also" section. I've edited my answer to include that information.